# Advertising downvote - still shown up

Tags: support, down-votes, advertising

Allthough I have been downvoting GTA5 ads on Stack Overflow several times I am *still getting them* repeatedly.

I had a look at my cookie settings according to the question ["How long does it take to get rid of an ad once you downvote it?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-rid-of-an-ad-once-you-downvote-it) and verified that *cookies* from *adzerk.net* as well as from *SO sites* are *allowed*.

Furthermore I did get the GTA ad multiple time on landing page of SO. So *tag-targeted placement* should not count too.

Did I miss something?

Comment: We do have 4 or 5 of these ads. Sorry they are annoying you so much.

Comment: To clarify: are you seeing the same ad or different ads?

Comment: I see the GTA5 ad - but I am not sure if it is the exact same GTA5 pic.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I ask because there are different solutions based on the issue experienced. If you are seeing the *exact same ad*, then the necessary solution will require much more digging than if you're seeing different GTAV ads. There are four different ones currently live, so it is very possible you haven't downvoted them all.

Comment: @stevvve ty for this input - just because I am curious I will note what GTAV ads I downvoted and add a comment if I downvoted the exact same ad twice!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I'm sure you have more important things to do, but any update here? I'd like to provide you with a definitive answer if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I just got another gtav ad - shall I post the image?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache since you first posted?

Comment: No - I haven't cleared cache since my first post

Comment: This question isn't relevant anymore since the functionality to like or dislike ads, with disliked ads not showing up later, was removed in 2015 when SE switched their ad network from Adzerk to Google.